# I have a problem with the vscode python extension, it's not displaying the quick info correctly

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed the latest version of python vscode extension , and when I click on the information icon, it shows me this
[method example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vmU84.png)

how can I enable quick information???

Comment: Hello, what did you expect to be displayed instead?

Comment: hi anto, i expect  information on how each method works

Comment: Which language server are you using: Jedi or MPLS?