# I have a problem with the vscode python extension, it's not displaying the quick info

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have installed the latest version of python vscode extension , and when I click on the information icon, it shows me this

[method example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RxTnI.png)

how can I enable quick information???

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. What is the "quick information" that you're mentioning?

Comment: hi Kos, python expansion includes intellisense, which allows for example to see what the function of each method, Unfortunately, it doesn't appear to me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have a problem with the vscode python extension, it's not displaying the quick info correctly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61599195/i-have-a-problem-with-the-vscode-python-extension-its-not-displaying-the-quick)